# How to open sites from same network?

Tags: iis-7.5

I have setup few websites on IIS 7.5.

All are working fine.

I have set binding for all sites like
`1. http www.example.com 80 unassigned (http://www.example.com)`
`2. http example.com 80 unassigned (http://example.com)`
`3. http 80 unassigned (http://localhost/)`

Now if I try `1` and `2` I get router page, because I am on same network as my server.  (that's ok) From outside network its working fine.

To view website I use http://server-name/ and it works because of binding no. `3`.

Now `3rd` binding i.e. localhost can only be set on one website on IIS.

I need that I will be able to access all my sites from local. Maybe Like:
http://server-name/site1
http:// server-name/site2

Please let me know how can I do this in one or the other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know of three ways to do this:

1. **Modify your local `hosts` file**. Modify your hosts file (in `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`) to put 'example.com' on the internal IP address.
2. **Use split DNS.** Change the internal DNS server to serve up `example.com` on an internal address instead of the external address.
3. **Use a separate domain.** Set up new sites on new names (example-internal.com or internal.example.com for instance) that you then enter into your internal DNS using the internal IP address.

All of these will allow you to use name-based virtual hosts from inside your network.

Comment: I don't understand, how to do any of these? Can you get me help link to do this?

Comment: @CharandeepSingh Then #1 is probably your best bet. The file has some example entries in it to get you started.

Comment: What I have done for now, I open a set of ports like 1000-1100 in firewall, and set one port per site. Like `example.com 1000 unassigned` so it works like http://server:1000/ etc.

Comment: Hello again, #1 works great. I just added domain names in my `hosts` file, its started working. Thanks a lot!